# For ios react native document picker not picking right path

Tags: react-native

whenever i am trying to get **real path** using react native document picker in ios platform i am getting wrong path.

***such as***

[Error: No such file 'file:///Users/krishna/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C37B4F69-052A-40FA-925C-984D4A3982BF/data/Containers/Data/Application/C837377B-E405-431B-8524-26B5A307506F/Documents/2E8A272D-A828-480E-B3E4-8BF6270BE0C9/file-sample_100kB.doc']

please give any solution

Comment: check permissions

Comment: where will i check permissions??and how will i give permissions??